# WndProc to detect device unplug and plug

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

How can I know a devices is plug or unplug in WPF?

I am using the code below to detect device changes:

```
   private void OnSourceInitialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                IntPtr windowHandle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
                HwndSource src = HwndSource.FromHwnd(windowHandle);
                src.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(WndProc));
            }

            private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
            {
                // Handle WM_DEVICECHANGE... 
                if (msg == 0x219)
                {
                    InitHead();
                }

                return IntPtr.Zero;
            }
```

Thank you.

EDITED:

I did the below, still not working:

```
if (msg == 0x0219)
            {
                switch (wParam.ToInt32())
                {
                    case 0x8000:
                        {
                            InitHead();
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: It work. but I want to know if the device is plug in or out.

Comment: RTFM: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480.aspx, DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL/DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE/etc.

Comment: I read that, but wParam does not return that.

Comment: Did you call RegisterDeviceNotification? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx

Comment: Maybe you can use something from this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

To detect if a device has been plugged in, , we add the hook to our `Window_Loaded` method that looks like the following

```
HwndSource source = HwndSource.FromHwnd(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle);
source.AddHook(new HwndSourceHook(this.WndProc));
```

The handler looks as follows:

```
private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    if (msg == 0x0219 && (int)wParam == 0x8000)  // 0x8000 is DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL
    {
        ProcessConnected();
    }

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Unfortunately, none of the DBT_DEVICE constants are triggered when a device is unplugged, rather they are called when you try to eject the device from Windows.